# Promise then block executing before completion of Post Request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, callback, axios

I am using axios to make a Post request to my Nodejs backend to use AWS S3 to pull Urls for specific data I need (not entirely relevant to issue but for context).

On the backend, I have an array with 12 entries that is initialized to "test" for each element. I then update specific elements in the array based on the json from the frontend. After I update one such element, I immediately console.log the entire array and it correctly has the updated array. When I console.log the entire array one last time before returning on the backend, all the entries are "test" but I understand this is probably because the console.log is not synchronous. However, when I return that array to the frontend and console.log the response the array is still all 12 "test", which is making me believe the 'then' block is executing before the Post request is even complete (which is confusing). I'm not sure what to do about this, because I need the proper array before I do my other data validation on the front-end. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried putting the post request in a separate function and returning that promise, but that isn't working either.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
//other code before
let json=JSON.stringify(data);
let post_data={json_data:json}

 this.grabData(post_data)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    var myObj = JSON.parse(response.data.json_data);
    console.log(myObj.length)
    var i;
    //Should output that certain elements have been changed, but all show up as 'test' still
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      console.log("element " + i + " is: " + myObj[i])
    }
    this.state.urls = myObj;
    var z;
    for (z = 0; z < 12; z++) {
      if (this.state.urls[z] === "test") {
        this.state.urls.splice(z, 1);
        z = z - 1;
      }
    }
    //The state.urls should not be empty after the splicing, but it is because all elements are still 'test' 
    console.log("After splicing: " + this.state.urls)
  });
}

grabData(post_data) {
  return axios.post('/getCharts', post_data)
}
```

And on the backend:

```
  app.post('/getCharts', (req, res) => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(req.body.json_data)
  let getThese = req.body[0]
  var urls = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"];
  var i;
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  console.log(year)

  let jan = ''
  let feb = ''
  let mar = ''
  let apr = ''
  let may = ''
  let jun = ''
  let jul = ''
  let aug = ''
  let sep = ''
  let oct = ''
  let nov = ''
  let dec = ''

  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i] == 1) {
      key = 'charts/pieChart' + year + '-01-01.png'
      console.log(key)
      var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key}

      s3.headObject(params, function (err, metadata) {
        if (!err) {
          urls[0] = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
        }
      });
    }
    if (obj[i] == 2) {
      key = 'charts/pieChart' + year + '-02-01.png'
      console.log(key)
      var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key}

      s3.headObject(params, function (err, metadata) {
        if (!err) {
          urls[1] = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
        }
      });
    }
    if (obj[i] == 3) {
      key = 'charts/pieChart' + year + '-03-01.png'
      console.log(key)
      var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key}

      s3.headObject(params, function (err, metadata) {
        if (!err) {
          urls[2] = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
          //This outputs a correctly updated array
          console.log(urls)
        }
      });
    }
    //This if block is repeated 12 times, up to obj[i] = 12, so removing for sake of simplicity
  }

  var i2;
  //This array prints out 12 'test' but I understand it's because console.log is executed async
  for (i2 = 0; i2 < 12; i2++) {
    console.log("urls" + i2 + " is: " + urls[i2])
  }

  let json=JSON.stringify(urls);

  let post_data={json_data:json}

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(post_data);
});
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're asking.  Maybe add some comments of what you expect in the code.  But in your `grabData(post_data)` request. You never return anything.  If you want data to come back to the client you need to `return this.state.urls` at the end of `grabData`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I initially had it so it would do axios.post(...).then((response) => ...) but I was told to try placing the post request in a separate function and returning that promise. So, the return axios.post('/getCharts', post_data) in grabData is meant to return the promise I suppose.

Comment: Can you include your `/getCharts` function.  It seems like that function isn't returning what you would expect.

Comment: Just edited the OP!

Comment: How confident are you that the server isn't just returning a bunch of 'test'? I'm pretty confident that it is.

Comment: additionally, `//This array prints out 12 'test' but I understand it's because console.log is executed async` isn't entirely true. Yes, console.log is async, but, because you're concatenating values, you will get the value of the thing at that moment in time, not when the console.log occurs. Therefore it being async is irrelevant.

Comment: It might be, as I console.log the array right before returning it from the backend and it prints all 'test' but I just wrote that off to the asynchronous nature of console.log. I thought that even though it was printing all 'test' there it would return the proper thing to the frontend.

Comment: Oh ok so do you think it could potentially be an issue with how I'm adjusting the values in the array?

Comment: Your issue is a case of returning a value from an async function. You're updating an array, after you've returned it to the client.

Comment: So the app.post('/getCharts') in the backend is returning the array before the for loop within it has terminated? If that's the case, what can I do to prevent that because it seems kind of odd that it would return before the entirety of the function is completed?

Comment: Yes your res.send() was happening before you even did any of the logic. My answer is a way to wait for the actions to happen then do your res.send()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend that Obj for loop is nasty code haha.. The reason for a for loop is to only do things once.  I cleaned up your code.  It should work. But if not this is the basic idea..

```
 app.post('/getCharts', (req, res) => {
  var obj = JSON.parse(req.body.json_data)
  let getThese = req.body[0]
  var urls = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "test"];
  var i;
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  console.log(year)

  let jan = ''
  let feb = ''
  let mar = ''
  let apr = ''
  let may = ''
  let jun = ''
  let jul = ''
  let aug = ''
  let sep = ''
  let oct = ''
  let nov = ''
  let dec = ''

        let uploads = 0;
    const finishedUpload = () => {
        uploads++;
        if (uploads === obj.length) {
              var i2;
              //This array prints out 12 'test' but I understand it's because console.log is executed async
              for (i2 = 0; i2 < 12; i2++) {
                console.log("urls" + i2 + " is: " + urls[i2])
              }

              let json=JSON.stringify(urls);

              let post_data={json_data:json}

              res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
              res.send(post_data);
        }
    }

  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    const myKey = i+1;
    if (obj[i] == myKey) {
      key = 'charts/pieChart' + year + '-0' + myKey +'-0' + myKey +'.png'
      console.log(key)
      var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key}

      s3.headObject(params, function (err, metadata) {
        if (!err) {
          urls[i] = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
          finishedUpload()
        }
      });
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried making those changes but still the same problem occurred for me. Do you think I need to change anything in my frontend code?

Comment: Wow okay I just played around with a couple small things from your answer and it worked! Thank you so much, you don't understand how long I've been trying to fix it haha.